Why are there (at least in the UK) two completely different-tasting kinds of "extra virgin olive oil"?
EDIT: In my question below, I asked about the existence of an apparent dichotomy that I've noticed in the taste of extra virgin olive oils; anticipating that my experience of this dichotomy might perhaps be due to my obtaining olive oil from UK supermarkets, I included mention of this and indicated in the question (and in the question title) that if the dichotomy does not exist as a general phenomenon then I am particularly interested in the case of oils typically sold in UK supermarkets.
However, I did not draw much attention to this point - which is good, because it has led to two responses informing me of what I did not know before, namely that dichotomy does not exist as a general phenomenon.
Nevertheless, this new information obviously does not automatically invalidate the phenomenon which I appear to have observed consistently and for which the purpose of this post is to seek an explanation: namely, that in UK supermarkets, there appears to be a sharp dichotomy between two flavour categories of olive oil.
Accordingly, I would now like to draw greater focus on this aspect of the question. Is it true that the vast majority of extra virgin olive oils sold in standard UK supermarkets can be divided into one of two categories of flavour, and if so, what is the cause of the difference? (I should emphasise that there may still be quite a large amount of variation of exact flavour within each category, but what defines the dichotomy is that the variations within each category are drastically smaller than differences in flavour between the two categories.)


In a typical supermarket in the UK, you will find a number of products labelled as

extra virgin olive oil

with the further description

superior category olive oil obtained directly from olives and solely by mechanical means.

Within one supermarket, these products will often vary greatly in price across a continuous price-spectrum. And yet my consistent experience is that, in terms of the taste, these products divide into two sharply distinct categories; there may be subtle flavour differences within each of the two categories, but across the two categories they simply taste like two different kinds of oil. And yet, I find nothing on the packaging that enables me to tell which of the two categories the product will be (apart from indirect evidences such as the Great Taste Award).

The first category -- which tends to be more expensive than the other, although the price-ranges of the two categories can have some overlap -- has a comparatively gentle "grassy" flavour, sometimes a little bit spicy [I guess this is what the adjective "peppery" means in the context of olive oil?], and sometimes a little bit bitter.
The second category has a much, much more "extroverted" flavour; it has an aspect of its flavour that, to my mind, tastes kind-of like a fusion of broccoli, mud and aluminium. This second category seems to be the much more commonly-found type of olive oil in restaurants, presumably because it is obtainable at a much cheaper price.

I even once remember reading an Amazon review of a fairly expensive olive oil of the first category [I can say that it is of the first category because I have tried it], where the reviewer was quite angry at having paid such a large amount of money for a product that "doesn't taste like olive oil", presumably because the reviewer (like myself until about 7 years ago) had only ever encountered olive oil of the second category!
Incidentally, I have encountered both Organic and non-Organic oils of the second category; I do not remember seeing Organic oil of the first category, but I certainly expect that it exists.
My question:
Am I right that there are these two sharply distinct kinds of "extra virgin olive oil" (at least in terms of what is typically sold in the UK)? And if so, where does this difference come from? (E.g. is it two different species of olive being used, or two different methods of oil-extraction, or a difference in post-extraction processing of the oil?)

Please note: This is not a question generically asking what the various factors are that can affect how olive oil tastes. I am asking specifically about what is responsible for the sharp dichotomy described above.

You are incorrect in your theory that there are "two distinct kinds of extra virgin olive oil."  Extra virgin simply refers to the oil gathered from the first "pressing".  Beyond that, quality and flavor range dramatically. There are numerous varieties of olive available, each with different characteristics. Within the extra virgin category single cultivars and blends can be found. Like wine grapes, single cultivars range dramatically in flavor, and terrior has a significant impact. Blends can come from a single plot of land or different plots, giving even more options for impacting flavor.  The oils from different countries can also be blended and sold as extra virgin. Another possible factor is extraction method, which also influences flavor.  These include, pressing, percolation, cold extraction, solvent extraction, and centrifugation.  See...lots of variables, which all influence the flavor of an olive oil.

Thanks for the useful information; please see my new "Edit" at the start of the question. Also, are you implying (like Fattie) that the variations in the olives themselves have a much bigger impact on the variety of flavours than variations in extraction/processing procedures for extra virgin olive oil?

@JulianNewman so many factors go into how an oil tastes, and a significant one is the variety of olive....but also see my edit above.

OP, to kick things off, my only answer would be,
"Olive oil has a (very) large range of flavors. The dichotomy you point to, simply doesn't exist. There's a (very) large range of flavors and while I understand the two you point to, they are not poles, attractors, they're just two of 'zillions'."
So, for me, to make an analogy it would be as if asking "among Chardonnay I've noticed two groups, zesty and stoney..." which would just be wrong.
And as a counter example, the question "among Scotch I've noticed two groups, peaty and the good one that's not-peaty" ... that would be "correct", if you see what I mean.
That's my take!  I'm afraid I have no evidence other than having consumer much olive oil - someone else may know more!

Thank you for drawing my attention to the fact that olive oil has a very large range of flavours. But you said that you do understand the two types of flavour that I pointed to - and so my second question still stands as to what factors are responsible for creating those two flavours (and my first question about the existence of the dichotomy also still stands, if you include my caveat about restricting to what is typically sold in a UK supermarket).

Right, I don't know what "leads to" the different flavors mentioned and other flavors.  My instinct is that it is indeed just the different fruit, plain and simple (just as wine tastes different depending on .. the grapes, ie when picked, what side of the hill, exact sub-type etc) rather than extraction process, or, post processing.  (Whereas with wine, in contrast the "extraction" etc methods result in hugely different alcohol, tastes etc: I'm saying for me olive oil is "just pressed olives".)

Lol of course this is really just a wild guess!
